# Cannot send table data which contains files, input data(string) to the server in .net aspx web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

On click of add button I add the product type, name and the file to the table.

The variables are declared globally.

```
document.getElementById("addBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var entryExists = false;
    var documentName = document.getElementById("chooseFileInput");
    var productNameValue = productNameDropdown.value;
    var file = documentName.files[0];

    var entryforTable = {
        product_Type: productTypeValue,
        product_Name: productNameValue,
        document_Name: file
    };

    var dataTable = document.getElementById("dataTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = dataTable.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var deleteCell = row.insertCell(3);

    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.textContent = "Clear";
    deleteButton.className = "btn btn-danger";
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        dataTable.removeChild(row);
        var index = tableData.indexOf(entryforTable);
        if (index > -1) {
            tableData.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    deleteCell.appendChild(deleteButton);

    cell1.innerHTML = entryforTable.product_Type;
    cell2.innerHTML = entryforTable.product_Name;
    cell3.innerHTML = file.name;

    tableData.push(entryforTable);
    productType.value = "";
    productNameDropdown.value = "";
    documentName.value = "";
});
```

On click of submit button I am sending the data to the server.

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var formData = new FormData();

    console.log(tableData);
    tableData.forEach(function (entry) {
        formData.append('productTypes[]', entry.product_Type);
        formData.append('productNames[]', entry.product_Name);
        formData.append('files[]', entry.document_Name);
    });

    console.log(formData);

    fetch("ThirdPartyProductDocsUpload.aspx/SaveFiles", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Response from server: " + data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
});
```

I have set the debugger on this function which doesn't get hit. But I get the response from Javascript as html which is incorrect.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveFiles(string jsonData)
{
    try
    {
        // Deserialize the JSON data into an array of objects
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Entry[] entries = serializer.Deserialize<Entry[]>(jsonData);

        // Validate input
        foreach (Entry entry in entries)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Product_Type) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Product_Name) || entry.Document_Name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input parameters.");
            }

            // Save the file
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(entry.Document_Name.FileName);
            string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TPPUploadFiles/");
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName);
            entry.Document_Name.SaveAs(filePath);

            // You can perform additional processing here if needed
        }

        return "Files uploaded successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

So basically, I want to send the table data to backend to save the files and product names.

Comment: I think you have to put [ScriptMethod] along with [WebMethod] for your "SaveFiles" method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using with:

```
JSON.stringify(formData);
```

And send it like that:

```
fetch("ThirdPartyProductDocsUpload.aspx/SaveFiles", {
        method: "POST",
        data: {
             jsonData: JSON.stringify(formData)
         }
    })
```